# Spring boot and java 8: Is there a way to build a string dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jira-rest-api

Is there a way to dynamically build a string in java 8 and/or spring boot? I'm trying to build an URL with parameters received from a REST Service call, this service has multiple optional filters, I can use the pseudo-AI method where I validate everything with multiple if-else but I don't think that's the best way to do it. This URL is a called to Jira REST Api so the syntax is something unique.

What I want to avoid is this

```
and = "\"%20AND%20\"";    
if (param1 != null) url += param1;
if (param1 != null && param2 != null) url += param1 + and + param2;
if (param1 != null && param2 != null && param3 != null) url += param1 + and + param2 + and + param3;
if (param1 != null && param2 == null && param3 != null) url += param1 + and + param3;
```

I think there must be a better way to do this than validating 10 times each parameter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you're asking for. Building strings dynamically would just be something like `s += "whatever";` which can be wrapped with if-statements. Of course if the strings have more structure you'll probably have to look for or create some builders that allow you to configure and finally build the string. It all depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: What is the relevance of the JPA example to your question?

Comment: @Bohemian sorry if it was confusing adding a JPA example, I wanted to see if there´s something like that for simple String, what I want to avoid is use a lot of if-else validations because I have 10 optional parameters and I would need to validate each a lot of times since I need to validate each with every param (let's say 100 times for this):
if(param1 != null) { url += param1 } 
if(param1 != null && param2 != null) { url += param1 + "\"%20AND%20\"" + param2 }...
And so with the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions available:

- just use a `StringBuilder` or simple string concatenation to build up your query string
- Springs `UriComponentsBuilder` [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)  provides a more structured way of building a query string and might be more familiar to your JPA based solution
- using `RestTemplates` allows to pass a conditionally filled `Map` representing your request parameters
- Springs newer `WebClient` class also supports setting paramters on a get using a uri builder like this:

```java
WebClient c = WebClient.create();
c.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
    .queryParam("param1", "value")
    .queryParam("param2", "value2")
    .build()
).retrieve();
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a combination between UriComponentsBuilder and RestTemplates, Jira has some unique sintaxis in its URI for REST Api so I had to replace the "&" that the UriBuilder added with the one that I needed, "%20", after that, it worked, I only had to validate each field once and nothing more